# Add Button to parent div statically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

**Definition**: I am creating a project that manages interns. Currently I am working at employee side; employees can add/edit/delete interns. These actions are handled by *modal popup*s.

**Approach**: In the purpose of avoiding unnecessary code, I created a layout modal.

```
<div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Intern</h3>
            </div>

            <div id="myModalContent"></div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">&nbsp;Cancel
                </button>

            </div>
        </div>
```

As you see, layout has CANCEL button. Because every modal should have cancel button, so best approach is placing it to layout.

```
<div id="myModalContent"></div>
```

This myModalContent part is filled by a javascript/ajax code. Script is putting **partial view**s to myModalContent. Also "Save Changes", "Delete Intern" etc.. buttons are coming from partial views.

**Problem:** But myModalContent is at another div, Cancel buttons are at another div. That causes a problem:

[image: example picture]

Edit Button code:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-default pull-right">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Edit Intern
        </button>
    </div>
```

I want these buttons at same row. As far as I know (from my researchs) I cant access parent div with css/html.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**Edit:**

Jquery code is here:

```
$(function () {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
$("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {
    $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
        $('#myModal').modal({
            keyboard: true
        }, 'show');
        bindForm(this);
    });
    return false;
});



function bindForm(dialog) {
$('form', dialog).submit(function () {
    $('#progress').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                $('#progress').hide();
                location.reload();
            } else {
                $('#progress').hide();
                $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                bindForm();
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: any reason why you are not using jQueryUI? then you could define the buttons in js.

Comment: Thats because I dont know jQueryUI (I've just heard it lol). This is my internship project and I am using jquery, javascript, html, css for just a week. AFAIK this is not an option. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In my opinion you are just adding parts of codes to this modal
It is obvious that edit and cancel buttons are down because you have a structure like that
<div id="myModalContent">
<div class="modal-footer"> there is edit intern button </div>
<div class="modal-footer"> there is cancel button</div>
</div>

So thats why it looks like it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get edit button from `myModalContent` and append it in `modal-footer` after loading partial view using below jquery

```
else {
       $('#progress').hide();
       $('#myModalContent').html(result);
       //move button from modal content to footer
       $('div.modal-footer').append($('#myModalContent button.btn.btn-default.pull-right'));
       bindForm();
       location.reload();
   }
```

If you want, edit button before cancel button then use `prepend()` instead of `append()`

Comment: I got your point, append the button to div. But it is not working because of me (I am newbie), where should I put this jquery?

Comment: just below the jquery code by which you are putting your partial view. Please post you jquery code, I will help you

Comment: I have update my answer, you need to add jquery code after `$('#myModalContent').html(result);`

Comment: This hasn't changed anything for now.

Comment: are you using first ajax call to load modal? then put my jquery code before `bindform` call

Comment: Its working, but at every edit clicking, extra edit button is adding preend to cancel button (more than one, at every click)

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle link with your problem statement, so that i can help you better